# Complex root of 1/x

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I know that there's no real root for $\frac{1}{x}$, but is there any complex root?

The reason I asked this question is that I had a course related to Taylor Series.

The green line in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEmmy.png) is $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, and the solution suggests that there are 2 complex roots for this function.

I am confused about how to solve the complex root for this kind of function...

Thanks in advance!

---

I added the image of the question & its answer.
[image: question]
[image: answer]

Comment: There are no complex numbers $x$ such that $\frac{1}{x} = 0$ or $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 0$. The solution is maybe referring to the denominator?

Comment: "the solution suggests..." - one of the curves is the parabola which has no real roots. Perhaps the makers of this website/test/whatever it is are just giving you by mistake the response that is appropriate to the parabola rather than $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$? I wouldn't dismiss such an error on their part.

Comment: This can't happen in any nontrivial ring. $1/x = 0$ would imply $1=0$.

Comment: It would help if we could see the question to which the image is an answer, not just the answer itself.

Comment: You are asking a wrong question, if you are trying to understand the answer in the image. I suggest, you edit again after thinking a bit about it.

Comment: That image is also wrong: the function is **not** discontinuous in the complex plane. It is not defined at two points, but that is different from being discontinuous.